# Writing to file if sprintf() buffer is overflow?

Tags: c

let's say I have this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFER_LEN 10
int main()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
    sprintf(buffer, "Oh noes, it's too long! What can I do?");

    return 0; 
}
```

Obviously it won't work since the buffer is too small to contain string. I know that there are different functions that can be used, and different memory handling for buffer. 
However my question is: is it possible to somehow check if buffer is overflown, and if so open text file and write to it, instead of putting it inside of the buffer.

Comment: Check the length of what you're trying to write against the size of the buffer? There's no built-in function to do what you want, so you need to roll it manually or find a library that does it.

Comment: That would mean that I have to store input I want to put via sprintf and check it's length with BUFFER_LEN or is there a way to access length of the second argument of sprintf() funtion, which in this case would be "Oh noes, it's too long! What can I do"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. Check the output length with `snprintf()` first:

```
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "Oh noes, it's too long! What can I do?");
```

And then you have `len` which you can do necessary evaluation and comparison.

From [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> #### Return value
>
> `snprintf()`: number of characters (not including the terminating null character) which would have been written to buffer if bufsz was ignored, or a negative value if an encoding error (for string and character conversion specifiers) occurred

So it will write a limited number of characters to the buffer (specified by the 2nd argument), and return **the length of the full data that would have been written**, which makes it a good function for string length evaluation.

Comment: @wildplasser Agree.

Comment: Thank you very much, that what I was looking for!

Comment: @wildplasser I guess you meant `strlen()` which I avoided on purpose.